# UITabBarItem badge value is null

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I'm using a service that give me a value to put into the `UITabBarItem` badge.
Sometimes it happens the follow issue:

[image]

I think it can be the delay for getting the badge value from the server, so I put the following code to keep it equals to the icon badge:

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber == 0) {
    [tabBarItem2 setBadgeValue:nil];
} else {
    [tabBarItem2 setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber]];
}
```

With this code the value of the badge on `UITabBarItem` should be the same of the badge icon of the app. I put this code in the method `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`, because I thought that this method is execute before other method. But when I try the app and I switch fast between the 3 view controller (home, notification and settings), sometimes it shows me null on the notification `UITabBarItem`. There's a way to don't show me the "null" value on the `UITabBarItem`?
Thank you

Comment: I think it has something to do with your other code, search setBadgeValue in your project and log them before you set it.

Comment: Thank you now it's working: it was a stupid issue during the check before setting the badge value